# Is there any way to get detected proxy from IE when "automatically detect proxy settings" option is used

Tags: internet-explorer, proxy, windows-8-preview, internet-explorer-10

in my IE in connection options selected option "automatically detect proxy settings". Is there any way to get which proxy server had been detected by IE (which IE is actually uses to connect to internet)?

Internet Explorer 10 and Windows 8.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you gone to internet settings?

Comment: Yes. In Tools->Internet Opnions->Connections->LAN Settings selected "Automatically detect settings"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you choose `automatically detect proxy settings` you are saying to IE to download a script from `http://wpad/wpad.dat` (normally).

This script can be quite involved and use a variety of proxy servers depending on various criteria - the source of the request, the destination, the hostname, the type of hostname etc.  So each individual request for a website could be conceivably be sent to a different proxy server.

There are a couple of things you can do - the first is to download a copy of `http://wpad/wpad.dat` yourself.  You can type this into your url and it will ask if you want to save it.  Then you can read it in a text viewer to see what the criteria are and so which proxy would be chosen (often there is only one).

The other thing you can do is go to a command prompt, and type `netstat -ban`. This will show all of the network connections from your machine, along with the process ID (PID) of the process that owns the connection.  If you look in Task Manager (enable the PID column) you can see the PID of iexplore.exe and so find out where it is sending its requests to (in the `Foreign Address` column of `netstat`). This will be the proxy server.

If you can switch to firefox, there are extensions that show you what IP address is serving you pages which would also tell you the proxy server IP.  There may be something similar for IE (but I doubt it - perhaps the web developer tools).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I'd thought I would share - In a corporate LAN that has multiple proxies, autodetect is the connection method, and we are not sure which proxy/location we are going out of, we type in the url of a site that we know is blocked (calottery.com for example - gambling) and the request is redirected to the proxy that was autodetected.  The IP address of that proxy will be revealed in the address bar of the browser.  Quick easy way to find out which proxy is being used